# How to subtract values between two particular dates in Powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table like this:

| DeviceID | SignalID | Value | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 1032223 | 01.10.2022 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 24 | 1923892 | 01.10.2022 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 33 | 3434342 | 01.10.2022 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 33 | 3232323 | 01.10.2022 00:00:00 |
| ....... | ...... | ...... | ...... |
| 1 | 33 | 4155151 | 05.12.2022 15:36:38 |

I have a few devices with each device monitoring signals. The signal value here represents some counter value. The counter are running continously but I need their relative value as in from 01.10.2022.

What I want to calculate :

The value of the signalID `x` of device `y` = (value now) - (value on 01.10.2022 00:00:00).

How can I acheive this for all the value of the signalID of all the devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can test this, and let me know if It solves your problem!

```
15Seconds_Cardinality =
VAR NowTime =
    NOW ()
VAR FixedTime =
    DATE ( 2022, 10, 01 ) + TIME ( 0, 0, 0 )
VAR Value_On_FixedDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( Signals[Value] ),
        YEAR ( Signals[DateTime] ) = YEAR ( FixedTime ),
        MONTH ( Signals[DateTime] ) = MONTH ( FixedTime ),
        DAY ( Signals[DateTime] ) = DAY ( FixedTime ),
        HOUR ( Signals[DateTime] ) = HOUR ( FixedTime ),
        MINUTE ( Signals[DateTime] ) = MINUTE ( FixedTime ),
        ROUND ( SECOND ( Signals[DateTime] ) / 15, 0 )
            = ROUND ( SECOND ( FixedTime ) / 15, 0 )
    )
VAR Value_On_Now =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Signals[Value] ),
        YEAR ( Signals[DateTime] ) = YEAR ( NowTime ),
        MONTH ( Signals[DateTime] ) = MONTH ( NowTime ),
        DAY ( Signals[DateTime] ) = DAY ( NowTime ),
        HOUR ( Signals[DateTime] ) = HOUR ( NowTime ),
        MINUTE ( Signals[DateTime] ) = MINUTE ( NowTime ),
        ROUND ( SECOND ( Signals[DateTime] ) / 15, 0 )
            = ROUND ( SECOND ( NowTime ) / 15, 0 )
    )
RETURN
    Value_On_Now - Value_On_FixedDate
```

Same above code with image file:

[image: GGL]

Comment: I tried to plot the graph using this Measure, but the plot  is empty.

Comment: Because It compares in terms of timestamp (seconds cardinality!!) I recommend you to replace now() function with today() function, and delete TIME(0,0,0) altogether, then test again! To summarize, You need to compare only date parts, not time parts!

Comment: But I need the time too as the database updates every minute.Using just the date will result in wrong calculation.

Comment: OK. Then you need to perform the DAX Code at minute cardinality. I will update the Code during the day(Sorry! I am too busy now!) If you want to give it a try, Then you need to change the filter context , and use the date(), hour() and minute() functions to get what you need.

Comment: @shakingwindow I updated the Code! please check it and let me know if It solves your prroblem!

Comment: Hi, the database gets updated every 10-15 seconds, so I won't be able to get the right values if i don't consider seconds.

Comment: You need to think alternative ways! I updated the code! test it!

Comment: @Ozar Sen It updates a single row,I dont know why, What i need in Value column is : 0,(1923892-1032223),(3434342 - 1923892),(3232323-3434342), instead I see : -1923892

Comment: You are comparing at 15-seconds interval and you are trying to catch a row match at this interval if Is this really what you want.